# Integration Tests for AWS Kinesis consumer built using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, microservices, amazon-kinesis

We are working on Micro service developed using spring boot which consumes data from Kinesis stream process it and then stores it in DB. We have good JUnit Mockito test coverage .Now we need Integration test on this . Can you please suggest a good framework or set of frameworks which can be used to test the entire application end to end . We have checked so far Citrus, and spring-integration-aws but no luck

Comment: Tests are bulshit. You don't need tests, you don't need framework, you need working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to run AWS services like Kinesis locally, and start them up from your integration tests using Docker commands or something like [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/).

Depending on how you have everything setup, you will need to inject a different Amazon Kinesis Client when the tests are running so that they connect to the local AWS services.